# How do I get elapsed time in milliseconds in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

If I have a `Time` object got from :

```
Time.now
```

and later I instantiate another object with that same line, how can I see how many milliseconds have passed? The second object may be created that same minute, over the next minutes or even hours.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

As stated already, you can operate on `Time` objects as if they were numeric (or floating point) values. These operations result in second resolution which can easily be converted.

For example:

```
def time_diff_milli(start, finish)
   (finish - start) * 1000.0
end

t1 = Time.now
# arbitrary elapsed time
t2 = Time.now

msecs = time_diff_milli t1, t2
```

You will need to decide whether to truncate that or not.

Comment: add a to_i and you have it as an integer, eg: ((finish - start) * 1000.0).to_i

Comment: `finish.to_f - start.to_f` ?

Comment: `finish - start` yields floating point; `.to_f` would be redundant.

Comment: If using rails or active support, you can use the #in_milliseconds method to do the same conversion `(t2 - t1).in_milliseconds`

Answer (score 61):

You can add a little syntax sugar to the above solution with the following:

```
class Time
  def to_ms
    (self.to_f * 1000.0).to_i
  end
end

start_time = Time.now
sleep(3)
end_time = Time.now
elapsed_time = end_time.to_ms - start_time.to_ms  # => 3004
```

Answer (score 34):

I think the answer is incorrectly chosen, that method gives seconds, not milliseconds.

```
t = Time.now.t­o_f
=> 1382471965.146
```

Here I suppose the floating value are the milliseconds

Comment: The chosen answer is correct. Using addition or subtraction on `Time.now` is treating the time as floating point values with seconds before the decimal point and up to nanoseconds after the decimal point (although nsec might not be completely accurate). So multiplying that value by `1000.0` yields miliseconds.

Comment: yes, but giving just "Time.now" is inaccurate and does not answer the question precisely.

Comment: This answer gives seconds, not milliseconds as desired.

Comment: @mfluehr the part after the dot are the milliseconds

Comment: @dfherr the chosen answer ignores the milliseconds information

Comment: @LowFieldTheory not sure why you replied to that again 6 years later, but you're still wrong. The chosen answer does not ignore the millisecond information. I already told you why and the comments to the chosen answer do too. The "to_f" is implicit on addition and subtraction and calling it explicitly is just redundant.

Comment: maybe it doesn't ignore, but it's easier to see the result sought for.
```
irb(main):001:0> Time.now()                                                                                                                           
=> 2023-05-30 17:04:50.5556 +0200                                                                                                                     
irb(main):002:0> Time.now().to_f()                                                                                                                    
=> 1685459096.4946408              
```

Answer (score 17):

```
DateTime.now.strftime("%Q")
```

Example usage:

```
>> DateTime.now.strftime("%Q")
=> "1541433332357"

>> DateTime.now.strftime("%Q").to_i
=> 1541433332357
```

Answer (score 13):

To get time in milliseconds, it's better to add `.round(3)`, so it will be more accurate in some cases:

```
puts Time.now.to_f # => 1453402722.577573

(Time.now.to_f.round(3)*1000).to_i  # => 1453402722578
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer is something like:

```
t_start = Time.now
# time-consuming operation
t_end = Time.now

milliseconds = (t_start - t_end) * 1000.0
```

However, the `Time.now` approach risks to be inaccurate. I found this post by Luca Guidi:

https://blog.dnsimple.com/2018/03/elapsed-time-with-ruby-the-right-way/

> system clock is constantly floating and it doesn't move only forwards. If your calculation of elapsed time is based on it, you're very likely to run into calculation errors or even [outages](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-and-why-the-leap-second-affected-cloudflare-dns/).

So, it is recommended to use `Process.clock_gettime` instead. Something like:

```
def measure_time
  start_time = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
  yield
  end_time = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
  elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
  elapsed_time.round(3)
end
```

Example:

```
elapsed = measure_time do
    # your time-consuming task here:
    sleep 2.2321
end

=> 2.232
```

Answer (score 9):

ezpz's answer is almost perfect, but I hope I can add a little more.

Geo asked about time in milliseconds; this sounds like an integer quantity, and I wouldn't take the detour through floating-point land. Thus my approach would be:

```
t8 = Time.now
# => Sun Nov 01 15:18:04 +0100 2009
t9 = Time.now
# => Sun Nov 01 15:18:18 +0100 2009
dif = t9 - t8
# => 13.940166
(1000 * dif).to_i
# => 13940
```

Multiplying by an integer 1000 preserves the fractional number perfectly and may be a little faster too.

If you're dealing with dates and times, you may need to use the **DateTime** class. This works similarly but the conversion factor is 24 * 3600 * 1000 = **86400000** .

I've found DateTime's **strptime** and **strftime** functions invaluable in parsing and formatting date/time strings (e.g. to/from logs). What comes in handy to know is:

- The formatting characters for these functions (%H, %M, %S, ...) are almost the same as for the C functions found on any Unix/Linux system; and
- There are a few more: In particular, **%L** does milliseconds!

Comment: Anyway %L exists only in Ruby 1.9 ;)

Answer (score 7):

`%L` gives milliseconds in ruby

```
require 'time'
puts Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L")
```

or

```
puts Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")
```

will give you current timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: This does not say how to get the elapsed time.

Answer (score 6):

[Time.now.to_f](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ref_c_time.html) can help you but it returns seconds.

In general, when working with benchmarks I:

- put in variable the current time;
- insert the block to test;
- put in a variable the current time, subtracting the preceding current-time value;

It's a very simple process, so I'm not sure you were really asking this...

Answer (score 3):

Try subtracting the first Time.now from the second. Like so:

```
a = Time.now
sleep(3)
puts Time.now - a # about 3.0
```

This gives you a floating-point number of the seconds between the two times (and with that, the milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something precise, unaffected by other part of your app (`Timecop`) or other programs (like NTP), use [`Process#clock_gettime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Process.html#method-c-clock_gettime) with `Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC` to directly get the processor time.

```rb
t1 = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
# other code
t2 = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
```

Also, if you are trying to benchmark some code tho, there is the [`Benchmark`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-realtime) module for that!

```rb
require "benchmark"

time = Benchmark.realtime do
  # code to measure
end
```