# Add 1 millisecond to a Time/DateTime object

Tags: ruby, time, milliseconds

Is there a way to add 1 millisecond to a Time/DateTime object in Ruby?

For an Webservice Request i need a time scoping with milliseconds:

```
irb(main):034:0> time_start = Date.today.to_time.utc.iso8601(3)
=> "2016-09-27T22:00:00.000Z"

irb(main):035:0> time_end = ((Date.today + 1).to_time).utc.iso8601(3)
=> "2016-09-28T22:00:00.000Z"
-- or --
irb(main):036:0> time_end = ((Date.today + 1).to_time - 1).utc.iso8601(3)
=> "2016-09-28T21:59:59.000Z"
```

So I'm near my prefered solution, but time_end should be `2016-09-28T21:59:59.999Z`.

I didn't find solutions that Ruby can handle calculating with milliseconds. I only did it with strftime, but it would be great if there is a possibility to calculate.

```
-- This works, but hard coded --
time_end = ((Date.today + 1).to_time - 1).utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.999Z")
=> "2016-09-28T21:59:59.999Z"
```

FYI: I'm on plain Ruby, no Rails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get elapsed time in milliseconds in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414951/how-do-i-get-elapsed-time-in-milliseconds-in-ruby)

Comment: *"I didn't find solutions that Ruby can handle calculating with milliseconds."* -- Here's the current timestamp, represented in milliseconds: `Time.now.to_f`

Comment: I dont want current Milliseconds i want calculation of the Time Object with it.

I need a 1 day scope beginning and end of day. And that in described iso format

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough. Is there a way to add 1 millisecond to a Time/DateTime Object?

Comment: why would you need this?

Comment: With your latest comment, we now know this is not a duplicate of the nominated examplar.  I've edit the question according to that comment.

Comment: Thx for editing!

@AndreyDeineko: Because i grab data from an webservice every day for that day. Our service provider build it with that iso formatting so i can define a begin and end time. When i do without that millisecond subtracted it is possible that i get data which was calculated for `2016-09-28T22:00:00.000Z` today as end scope and tomorrow as beginning scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok i found a solution. With real calculation i looks like.

```
time_end = ((Date.today + 1).to_time - 1/1001).utc.iso8601(3)
=> "2016-09-28T21:59:59.999Z"
```

**EXAMPLE**

Formatting in iso8601(3) is only to show behavior.

```
irb(main):055:0> Date.today.to_time.iso8601(3)
=> "2016-09-28T00:00:00.000+02:00
```

Adding a millisecond"

```
irb(main):058:0> (Date.today.to_time + 1/1000.0).iso8601(3)
=> "2016-09-28T00:00:00.001+02:00"
```

Subtract a millisecond

```
!DONT USE, see result with subtracted 2 milliseconds!
irb(main):060:0> (Date.today.to_time - 1/1000.0).iso8601(3)
=> "2016-09-27T23:59:59.998+02:00"

USE
irb(main):061:0> (Date.today.to_time - 1/1001.0).iso8601(3)
=> "2016-09-27T23:59:59.999+02:00"
```